# Use property for composition attribute

Tags: objective-c, properties, attributes

I have an objective c class **A** that owns a c++ class **B** that has a velocity attribute.

Is it ok to use

`@property(nonatomic) float velocity;`

in class **A** even if that class does not have an velocity attribute. When I implement the 
velocity function I will ask **B** and return that value, so it's kind of an implicit attribute of class **A**.

I guess it works, so my question is if it is good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely fine. Assuming that you have implemented the getter and setter correctly there is no requirement that a class with a property have a member variable at all!

Though you might run into problems with KVO - this property isn't KVO compliant. That's almost certainly not a problem though :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with this approach. If you ensure that the C++ header is included only from the implementation file of the Objective C class, then you can present a pure Objective C interface, which I would consider to be of more importance. The property is a value type so it's value is copied when the property is accessed. When looked at in this way, nothing of the implementation of the Objective C class escapes when the property is accessed. You would be free to change the property implementation at any stage in the future without changing any clients of the API.

The property should be marked assign to specify the it has value semantics.

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) float velocity;
```